# Is contiguous memory easier to get in a 64-bit address space? If so why?

Tags: memory-management, jvm, 64-bit

A [comment](https://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/why_can_t_i_allocate#comment-1090515226000) in [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/why_can_t_i_allocate) states:

> We know how to make chunked heaps, but there would be some overhead to
>   using them. We have more requests for faster storage management than
>   we do for larger heaps in the 32-bit JVM. If you really want large
>   heaps, switch to the 64-bit JVM. We still need contiguous memory,
>   **but it's much easier to get in a 64-bit address space**.

This implication of the above statement is that it is easier to get contiguous memory in a 64-bit address space. Is this true? If so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very true.  A process must allocate memory from the virtual memory address space.  Which stores both code and data and whose size is restricted by the addressing capability of the architecture.  You can never address more than 2^32 bytes in a 32-bit process, not counting bank-switching tricks.  That's 4 gigabytes.  The operating system typically takes a big chunk out of that as well, on 32-bit Windows for example that cuts down the addressable VM size to 2 gigabytes.

Ideally, allocations are made so that they fit snugly together.  That very rarely works out in practice.  Shared libraries or DLLs in particular need to pick a preferred load address and that has to be guessed up front when the library is built.

So in practice, the allocations are made from the holes in between existing ones and the largest possible *contiguous* allocation you can get is restricted by the size of the largest hole.  Usually much smaller than the addressable VM size, on Windows it is typically around 650 megabytes.  That tends to go down-hill from there as the available address space is getting *fragmented* by allocations.  Particularly by native code that can't afford to have allocations moved by a compacting garbage collector.  If you use Windows then you can get insight in the VM allocations with the SysInternals' VMMap utility.

This problem completely disappears in a 64-bit process.  The theoretical addressable virtual memory size is 2^64, an enormous number.  So large that current processors don't implement it, they can go up to 2^48.  Further restricted by the operating system version you have and its willingness to keep page mapping tables for that much VM.  Eight terabytes is a typical limit.  By implication, the holes between allocations are *huge*.  Your program will keel over on paging file thrashing before it dies from OOM.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for how the JVM is implemented obviously, but from a purely theoretical viewpoint, if you have a significantly larger virtual address space (eg 64-bit as compared with 32-bit) it should be significantly easier to find a large block of contiguous memory which is available for allocation (going to extremes - you've got no chance of finding a contiguous 4GB of free memory in a 32-bit address space, but a significant chance of finding this space in a full 64-bit address space).

It should be noted that whatever the virtual address space size, this is still going to be implemented by allocation of (probably) non-contiguous physical memory pages, particularly if the requested allocation is large - the larger virtual address space just means there are a likely to be a lot more contiguous virtual addresses available for use.